# Как в APACHE и PHP подменить код ответа 500 на 200?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

В логах есть такое предупреждение (ответ 500)

```
[fcgid:warn] [pid 5043] (32)Broken pipe: [client 217.66.154.23:52494] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

как можно подменить его , чтобы отдавал 200 код ?
Я имею в виду , что-то типа  :

```
if($WARNING == "Broken pipe")
header("Status: 200 OK");
```

Comment: 1) То есть вы хотите обмануть пользователя, скрыв факт существования проблемы? https://i.giphy.com/media/Yl5aO3gdVfsQ0/giphy.gif

Comment: 2) Ну и, пожалуй, самое главное — почему бы не найти и устранить саму причину возникновения ошибки «Broken pipe» вместо того чтобы маскировать её 200-м ответом?

Comment: спасибо за ваши однотипные ответы ко всем моим постам. Вопрос был "как сделать" ?

Comment: И какое тело ответа вы хотите тогда?

Comment: мне надо, чтобы бот яндекса перестал слать уведомления, что страница недоступна , когда она доступна . Причина только в том, что бот обрывает соединение, из-за этого получает ошибку 500 (broken pipe) . Мне надо , чтобы этот warning отдавал 200 статус. Никак на обычных юзерах это не отражается

Comment: Если бот обрывает соединение, то он в принципе никак не сможет получить ни 500 ни 200, потому что он уже оборвал соединение и перестал получать данные от сервера. У вас проблемы с логикой

Comment: вы если не хотите помочь или просто не знаете - идите лесом. Если бы вы хоть потратили 2минуты и нашли в интернете описание данной ошибки , то не писали бы всего бреда. Вопрос был "как подменить ответ", а не про то , как и что лучше

Comment: К сожалению, пока что бред здесь пишете только вы, а помочь с бредом мы вряд ли сможем